# Who drew this hollow Moon theory picture?

Tags: story-identification, history, art

I would like to use this hollow Moon picture on my site (from [elarcadelosdioses.wordpress.com](https://elarcadelosdioses.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/luna-hueca.jpg)):

[image]

Here is a similar contrast photo of the Moon from [space.com](http://www.space.com/55-earths-moon-formation-composition-and-orbit.html):

[image]

It appears often and w/o any credentials. Depicting some engines inside of the Moon and looks medieval.

Who is the author?

Comment: It doesn't look medieval to me, for what it's worth. I wouldn't peg it as any older than 1940s.

Comment: Yes, probably, since light beams look modern. I.e. author knew how they may look. But it's b/w

Comment: @Dims Architecture looks modern as well.

Comment: @called2voyage Before photographic plates - was the appearance of the moon's surface documented so clearly? I'll be a comparison of the drawn/sketched surface to the real moon's surface from a photo would give some clues as well.

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, I was thinking about that too, but wasn't sure enough to note it.

Comment: @uhoh [1647 map of the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenography#/media/File:Hevelius_Map_of_the_Moon_1647.jpg)

Comment: @called2voyage I estimate the resolution of the moon's surface in the larger image is about 2 pixels. The moon is about 580 pixels wide. So the resolution is roughly a half-dozen arc seconds.

Comment: it's definitely common. I have a hunch it may be connected to Sherbakov's 1968 article about hollow Moon. Alas, that article is not on the internet

Comment: Earliest copy I can find: https://www.flickr.com/photos/45369733@N03/4169379961 The uploader even named it "copy", and based on their other content they are not the original user. That's 2008. Before that it's like it didn't exist.

Comment: The architecture appears to imply a downward gravity, not an inward gravity. Note the structure underneath the central ring.

Comment: I'm interested too. Anyone who comes up with a plausible answer can have a 500 bounty from me too.

Comment: I found this image on the Mirror website, and they credited this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkSX68ZXUgg

Comment: found the same photo in this site : https://illuminutti.com/2015/03/14/our-moon-is-an-alien-ufo-spaceship-parked-in-orbit-around-earth-ufologists-claim/

Comment: This image is *extremely* prolific, mainly on crack/conspiracy websites such as illuminati.com etc. Not a single user credits the original author though.

Comment: I've delved far too deep into "that part" of the web for my liking and am not willing to continue further. All I can see is that image started making the rounds in about 2014 onward and keeps on circling back to the same few locations. Given that those particular sites don't like giving references or sources, I'd doubt that you'd find Good luck.

Comment: I found the oldest source in 2014 using tiny eye reverse search https://www.tineye.com/search/fd54c7e2ca1bc67ae603393f0343d86398131a4c/?sort=crawl_date&order=asc

Comment: Has anyone checked the art of Chesley Bonestell?  He did a lot of space art back in the 1940s up into the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling, this is just a Photoshop/Edited picture by someone who did not publish it with his name to begin with.

There are a lot of depictions very similar to the one you posted.

On [this ufo sightings page](http://www.ufosightingsdaily.com/2016/10/giant-ufos-near-earths-moon-reinforce.html) for example, we see roughly the same picture with a different colouring.

[This one](http://www.disclose.tv/news/the_hollow_moon_theory_is_the_moon_hollow/132013) is the same picture, only darker.

And [right here](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/the-moon-hollow), we have another version of what appears to be a lower resolution picture, with credits to **Pinterest**.

The Pinterest tip leads to [this user](https://www.pinterest.de/thatbclassified/) (Pinterest account may or may not be neccessary to view).

The Pinterest post cites [thatsclassified.com](http://thatsclassified.com/) as source. Finding the picture on this site, or even articles about the hollow-moon theory is extremely difficult, most articles are archived already as it seems.

I hope this at least helps you find your way to the author a little faster.

Comment: Well then, we need to find the person who drew the "insides" of that station.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I did an image search with just a clipping of the inside image. There were no instances of it apart from the moon. If there is prior art, I don't think it's on the web.